# Mule4 consuming rest API(s)

Tags: java, spring-boot, httprequest, mulesoft, mule4

`localhost:8081/getproduct/? productids=5d668dab0be6a263d464e822&productids=5d668daf0be6a263d464e823`

have this API. How to set it in query param of mule4? I am using set variable for that but then I am able to pass only one **productid** using `attribute.queryParams.productIds`, but I need to pass list of **productIds**. How to do it using `setVariable`?

Comment: do you have RAML definition of productid's, you will need to pass them as `,` separated values and define it as string or use For each when passing multiple Id's

Comment: How to use For each in set variable?

Comment: wrap HTTP connector in For each, you wont need to set  a variable, Please give us more info about RAML , type of get query params. If they are in an array, send them across in for each

Comment: Thank you so much it got resolved I've done it using setPayload